# Comma symbol could be ignored while passing params into a function?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm a newbie that is learning Swift from [SwiftLanguageGuide-Concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html) and feel confused while reading codes:

```swift
let firstPhoto = await listPhotos(inGallery: "Summer Vacation")[0]
add(firstPhoto toGallery: "Road Trip")
remove(firstPhoto fromGallery: "Summer Vacation")
```

Why here has no comma after the param `firstPhoto` in function `add` and `remove`?

IMO the grammar should be:

```swift
add(firstPhoto, toGallery: "Road Trip")
remove(firstPhoto, fromGallery: "Summer Vacation")
```

So the comma symbol could be ignored while passing params into a function in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're typos. You should report them. Other people will find it confusing too.

Comment: It has already been fixed in the repository: https://github.com/apple/swift-book/commit/d9995a7934e4c9ad47d920cd4584e7507325cf1a

Comment: Thank you... Never imagine Apple's official guid would have mistake OMG.